# Displaying a Picker View selection in another ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, segue, picker

I am fairly new to Swift and am trying to have the item I select in my picker view display on a label on another screen. I know that when I want pass data from one page to another I need to use the prepareForSegue function but I cant figure out how to pass data from a picker view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource protocols to get data from the picker view.

If you're just using it as an input for a text field, you can simply just set `textField.inputView = pickerView` instead of having the picker view on another controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can send data trough prepareForSegue.first of all we need a variable to declare in another view controller.

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "send_data") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! secondview;






        //you can get selected value on pickerview
        var selectedValue = pickerData1[pickerview1.selectedRowInComponent(0)]

        var pic1 = String(selectedValue)
        print("picker1 count :----------\(pic1)")


        //datapassed is the variable we declare in another view control.
        svc.dataPassed=pic1

           print("pic1 is :\(pic1)")
    }
}
```

//second view controller.which lable has.

var dataPassed:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
   var getpassdata = String(dataPassed)



    txt.text=getpassdata


}
```